# Defining a proper __repr__ in Python

Tags: python, string

Just learning Python and trying to lear about making classes.  I have a class "Bag" defined.  For `__str__` I have:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "<Bag: '{}' with {} items >".format(self.name, len(self.data))
```

It gives me back:

```
<Bag: 'mystuff' with 3 items >
```

For `__repr__` I am trying to get back: `<Bag: 'mystuff' with apple (1), pear (2) >`

I'm completely lost on how to format that string, however.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So what type is `self.data` here?

Comment: def __init__(self, item):
        self.data = []
        self.name = item

Comment: So you append items to that?

Comment: Yes, I append and end up with a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

def __repr__(self):
    counter = Counter(self.data)
    items = ', '.join('%s (%s)' % (name, count) for name, count in counter.iteritems())
    return "<Bag: '{}' with {} >".format(self.name, items)
```